# Visual representation of difference between closed, bounded and compact sets

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I have trouble grasping the difference between bounded, closed and compact sets. As a picture is worth a thousand words (especially for a person with a light math background), I would like to get a graphical representation of those concepts.

Definitions:

**Bounded set**
A set having all its points lie within some fixed distance of each other. A set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded if all of the points are contained within a ball of finite radius

**Closed set**
A set containing all its limit points. The closure of the set is equal to the set.

**Compact set**
compactness is a property that generalizes the notion of a subset of Euclidean space being closed and bounded

Here is a figure that I took from [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1190640/what-is-the-difference-between-closed-and-bounded-in-terms-of-domains/2527850) and modified:

[image: bounded_closed_compact]

**my question**

Can we say that the subfigures ($1$) and ($4$) of the figure are compact?

Comment: Yes to the last question. Your first example is wrong. That set is closed and bounded - it's just the origin. (Perhaps that's a typo.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment @EthanBolker. I removed the example and just left the definition and figure. Is everything correct now?

Comment: In $\mathbb R^n$, closed and bounded means compact

Comment: Thank you for your comment @J.W.Tanner. So we can indeed say that the subfigures (1) and (4) of the figure are compact. Correct?

Comment: Everything is right now. The only example missing (for logical completeness) is the fourth possibility: not closed and not bounded (necessarily not compact, of course).

Comment: Thank you @EthanBolker. And this example would be then for example a visual representation of a space $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @ecjb:  You're correct; these are in $\mathbb R^2$

Answer (score 1):

A subset of $\mathbb R^n$ (e.g., $\mathbb R^2$, in your depictions) is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.  As you showed, a subset could be closed but not bounded, or it could be bounded but not closed.  It could also be neither closed nor bounded [such as $\mathbb R^2\setminus  (0,0)]$.  In any of those cases, it is not compact.  As you alluded to, compact can be defined for topological spaces in general (every open cover has a finite subcover), but the Heine-Borel theorem states that for $\mathbb R^n$, a subset is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.